# Solve $\arcsin (\frac{2x}{x^2+1})= \arctan(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve the next equation:

$$
\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right)=\arctan(x)
$$
When I pose $\tan \left(\frac{t}{2}\right) =x$
I obtain, after some simplifications, $t = \frac{t}{2}$.

I know $\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{-\pi}{3}$ are answers but can't seem to get them.
Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I pose tan t/2 = x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin\arctan{x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}},$ we need to solve
$$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}},$$ which gives the answer:
$$\{0,\sqrt3,-\sqrt3\}.$$

Comment: how can we know there won't be problems with the periodicity of the $\sin$ and $\tan$ functions?

Comment: @RGS It's not relevant here because $\arcsin\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\arctan\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: @RGS Note that the periods play a role when we apply inverse trig functions, but to solve in the way Michael suggests we're actually just applying the regular trig functions.

Comment: Thanks! I can take it from here !

Comment: @spooktober You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

Draw the unit circle and, through triangle similarities, find expressions for:

$$\tan\left(\arcsin(\omega) \right)$$

and

$$\sin\left(\arctan(\omega) \right)$$

Now take your original equation and either apply $\tan$ to both sides or $\sin$ to both sides, and see what you can get from there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $\angle BCA=\arctan(x)$ and so $x=\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac{x}{1}$. This gives $AB=\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Thus $\sin(\arctan(x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. Now you need to solve $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image: Abdul Halim]

The solution is ,

$x=0$,

$x=-\sqrt{3}$,

$x=\sqrt{3}$

Comment: This is duplicating a previous answer without even showing a derivation. Why are you posting this after 1 1/2 years?

Comment: Today same question is asked someone.I did it and show a graphical picture to make it very clear.